# Lightning Route Discovery - How to know capacity in each direction?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing

So i have a question how routing works in the LN. I read partly through the RFC described in https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc but I have still this open question.

I know every node in LN has the whole network topology information, so it knows each node and each channel and with that also the capacity of a channel. But the capacity of a channel doesn't say which side is owning how much. How can we find now a valid route and be sure that there is enough capacity in each channel for the direction which is part of our route?

So for an example lets say I am node A und have a channel to node B and this one has a channel to node C. Lets say each channel has a capacity of 1 BTC, I want to send now 0.4 BTC from A to C and chose the route A -> B -> C. But now it may be that in the channel B - C the node B only owns 0.3 BTC at the moment and node C owns 0.7 BTC. That would mean that B can't send 0.4 to node C. So if I send now this transaction B would return with an error.

If I have now a longer route the possibility of such an event increases exponentially. So at the end it is very unlikely that my chosen route is valid. How does the protocol prevent a lot of tries until one finds a really valid route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you did find such a route successfully, what guarantees that B WILL use its payment channel? B can deny at any moment, because decentralization.

Also, from [routing recommendations](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/07-routing-gossip.md#recommendations-for-routing):

> When calculating a route for an HTLC, the `cltv_expiry_delta` and **the
>   fee** both need to be considered: the `cltv_expiry_delta` contributes to
>   the time that funds will be unavailable on worst-case failure. **The
>   tradeoff between these two is unclear, as it depends on the
>   reliability of nodes.**

Goes on to explain that the problem is deeper:

> If a route is computed by simply routing to the intended recipient,
>   summing up the `cltv_expiry_deltas`, then nodes along the route may
>   guess their position in the route. Knowing the CLTV of the HTLC and
>   the surrounding topology with the `cltv_expiry_deltas` gives an attacker
>   a way to guess the intended recipient. Therefore it is highly
>   suggested to add a random offset to the CLTV that the intended
>   recipient will receive, bumping all CLTVs along the route. In order to
>   create a plausible offset the sender MAY start a limited random walk
>   on the graph, starting from the intended recipient, sum the
>   `cltv_expiry_deltas`, and then use the sum as the offset. This
>   effectively creates a *shadow route extension* to the actual route,
>   providing better protection against this kind of attack than simply
>   picking a random offset.

Importantly for this answer, it ends at:

> Other **more advanced considerations** involve diversity of routes to
>   avoid single points of failure and detection and channel balance of
>   local channels.

So the answer would be, that LN just provides discovery, doesn't build a path(because a channel cannot be guaranteed to be online in a decentralized network??) so 'tries' is not a feature of core LN(but of the [autopilot](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/tree/master/autopilot) feature).

The autopilot can be seen [here](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/commit/306c4aef8e3af44fb3f2d8f52fc887f2c48e9c04). This is where the `heuristics` for finding the path goes.

> The autopilot package has been signed to be as abstract as possible in
>   order to allow users, developers, and researchers to plug in various
>   heuristics in order to experiment with the possibilities, or attempt
>   to optimize the channel sub-graph for their targeted nodes. The
>   current default heuristic is a mode called `ConstrainedPrefAttachment`.

Also,

> This is only one example of the
>   possible heuristics which could be hooked into an active
>   `autopilot.Agent` instance. We look forward to the additional heuristics
>   that developers/researchers will implement!

In short, the current heuristic implementation first [selects a slice](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/autopilot/prefattach.go#L156) in the network, and then [greedily allocates funds](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/autopilot/prefattach.go#L250).

```
switch {
    // If we have enough available funds to distribute the maximum channel
    // size for each of the selected peers to attach to, then we'll
    // allocate the maximum amount to each peer.
    case int64(fundsAvailable) >= numSelectedNodes*int64(p.maxChanSize):
        for i := 0; i < int(numSelectedNodes); i++ {
            directives[i].ChanAmt = p.maxChanSize
        }

        return directives, nil

    // Otherwise, we'll greedily allocate our funds to the channels
    // successively until we run out of available funds, or can't create a
    // channel above the min channel size.
    case int64(fundsAvailable) < numSelectedNodes*int64(p.maxChanSize):
        i := 0
        for fundsAvailable > p.minChanSize {
            // We'll attempt to allocate the max channel size
            // initially. If we don't have enough funds to do this,
            // then we'll allocate the remainder of the funds
            // available to the channel.
            delta := p.maxChanSize
            if fundsAvailable-delta < 0 {
                delta = fundsAvailable
            }

            directives[i].ChanAmt = delta

            fundsAvailable -= delta
            i++
        }

        // We'll slice the initial set of directives to properly
        // reflect the amount of funds we were able to allocate.
return directives[:i:i], nil
```

[EDIT:straight answer]

> So the heuristic only uses the channel capacity to find a route?

"based on the current internal state, the state of the channel graph, the set of nodes we should exclude, and the amount of funds available"

> Does the path finding heuristic have the information which side of a channel in the network owns how much, or does it only compute a route based on the capacity of channels?

Looking at the [spec example](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/routing/testdata/spec_example.json), we only get info of "capacity" of an "edge" in the graph and **not how much each party owns**; only the amount they are willing to transmit. As explained above, yes, it depends on capacity, but it has more properties and not just amounts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't really understand how the heuristic works. So the heuristic only uses the channel capacity to find a route? So what my initial question was: Does the path finding heuristic have the information which side of a channel in the network owns how much, or does it only compute a route based on the capacity of channels?

Comment: @blacktemplar edited the answer. I hope it answers your query. If not please ask for more clarification.